# Create a SKSpriteNode that blurs the nodes below

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit, uiblureffect

I want to create a Sprite that has an alpha value and sits on top of some other nodes.

```
let objects = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "objects")
let blurredOverlay = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "overlay")
addChild(objects)
addChild(blurredOverlay)
```

My intention is to add a visual effect to the 'blurredOverlay' Node so that only the nodes that are overlapped by this node show the blurred effect?

Anyone with an idea?

Answer (score 1):

*This answer take and modify code from: [Add glowing effect to an SKSpriteNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40362204/add-glowing-effect-to-an-skspritenode)*

For you solution:

**Swift 3**

```
let objects = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "objects")
let blurredOverlay = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "overlay")

let effectNode = SKEffectNode()
    effectNode.shouldRasterize = true
    effectNode.zPosition = 1
    effectNode.alpha = 0.5
    effectNode.addChild(SKSpriteNode(texture: blurredOverlay.texture))
    effectNode.filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur", withInputParameters: ["inputRadius":30])
    objects.addChild(effectNode)


addChild(objects)
```

Example: (Up tree have a blurredOverlay)

[image]

On the example images "objects" and "overlay" are the same image.