# Is it possible to put a filter effect (like Sepia) over a SpritKit Scene?

Tags: ios, swift, filter

Is it possible to put some kind of a photo filter effect over SpriteKit Scene?

I am creating a game and at certain points I'd like to make it more difficult with a effect like Sepia, Black&White, Chrome or something similar.

So far I have just created an image which I present with a low alpha value over the scene as a SKSpriteNode, but that is not really what I want, a realtime filter like Black&White would be better.

Comment: Have you tried using CoreImage?

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: So far I just did productivity apps and never used CoreImage or SpriteKit before. SpriteKit is quite easy but still all new terrain for me.

Comment: SpriteKit and UIKit are very separate frameworks. A quick search gave me this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490818/how-do-i-blur-a-scene-in-spritekit#22494746), which tells me it *is* possible to use CI in certain SK classes. The effort may not be worth it, but then again, it may make your app a bit more unique.

Comment: Cheers. I am going to try this.

Comment: Have a look at this example [Add glowing effect to an SKSpriteNode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40362874/1761687)